# github public repos anyone branch (instead of only fork)

Tags: git, github

I want anyone to be able to make a branch in my public github repos. I have turned on protection for the main branch. I want anyone to be able to branch, not just fork.

How do I accomplish this permission setting?

Answer (score 1):

GitHub doesn't let just anyone modify someone else's repository, whether the repository is public or private.  There are many reasons for this, including that it makes it hard to trust the contents of a repository in terms of security and functionality when arbitrary people can modify a repository.  Even if *you* don't care about this, other people rely on this security model existing.

The only way to allow people to contribute to your repository is either forking or explicitly adding them as contributors to your repository.

Comment: Yes, I realise that. I think though that if I've turned on branch protection for the main branch, it's then up to me if I want to make it possible for others to make branches. I understand how that's not the default, for the reasons you mention, but I'd like the option.

Answer (score 1):

I believe any user with access to the repo as a collaborator can create branches.

But if you are talking about people who are not collaborators, maybe if you create a branch protection rule and in the name add the wildcard `*` symbol, and uncheck all options, could work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm.. not entirely sure how that would work but I'll try. I've got a branch protection on for the main branch.
What I want is that anyone, even if they're not collaborators, can create a branch.